# Strongly additive open cover

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, connectedness

> Call an open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of a metric space $M$ *strongly additive* if whenever $U,V\in\mathscr{U}$ and $U\cap V\ne\emptyset$, then $U\cup V\in\mathscr{U}$. Prove that $M$ is compact and connected if and only if every strongly additive open cover of $M$ contains $M$.

My proof:

**(1) If $M$ is not compact, there exists a strongly additive open cover of $M$ that doesn't contain $M$.**

Suppose $M$ is not compact. Then it has an open cover $\mathscr{U}$ with no finite subcover. Consider this cover, appended by all finite unions of sets in this cover. It is strongly additive, and it does not contain $M$.

**(2) If $M$ is not connected, there exists a strongly additive open cover of $M$ that doesn't contain $M$.**

Suppose $M$ is not connected. Then it can be partitioned into two disjoint, nonempty open subsets $A,B$. Take this as a cover. It is strongly additive, and it doesn't contain $M$.

**(3) If there exists a strongly additive open cover of $M$ that doesn't contain $M$, then $M$ is not compact or not connected.**

Suppose there exists a strongly additive open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $M$ that doesn't contain $M$. Consider the collection $\mathscr{V}\in\mathscr{U}$ of sets in $\mathscr{U}$ that are not a proper subset of any other set in $\mathscr{U}$. Note that $\mathscr{V}$ still covers $M$, because any set in $\mathscr{U}$ outside $\mathscr{V}$ is a subset of some set in $\mathscr{V}$. Also, any two sets in $\mathscr{V}$ are disjoint, because otherwise their union belongs to $\mathscr{U}$, and each of them is a proper subset of their union. So the open cover $\mathscr{V}$ consists of disjoint open sets. Since $M\not\in\mathscr{V}$, $\mathscr{V}$ consists of at least two elements. Let $A\in\mathscr{V}$. Let $B$ be the union of all sets in $\mathscr{V}$ beside $A$. $B$ is open as a union of open sets. Then $A,B$ are disjoint, nonempty open subsets of $M$ whose union is $M$. So $M$ is not connected.

In (3), I didn't have to use the condition "or compact". Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT**: Second try on (3) -- used the compactness following Tim's comment

Suppose there exists a strongly additive open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $M$ that doesn't contain $M$, and that $M$ is compact. We'll show that $M$ is not connected. Since $M$ is compact, $\mathscr{U}$ has a finite subcover $\mathscr{U}'$. Take all unions of sets in $\mathscr{U}'$ and add it to $\mathscr{U}'$ -- note that $\mathscr{U}'$ still doesn't contain $M$, and is now strongly additive. Consider the collection $\mathscr{V}\in\mathscr{U}$ of sets in $\mathscr{U}'$ that are not a proper subset of any other set in $\mathscr{U}'$. Note that $\mathscr{V}$ still covers $M$, because any set in $\mathscr{U}'$ outside $\mathscr{V}$ is a subset of some set in $\mathscr{V}$. Proceed as in the old step (3).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is where you went wrong but the sentence "any set in $\mathscr{U}$ outside $\mathscr{V}$ is a subset of some set in $\mathscr{V}$" isn't obviously true to me.

Comment: @Timkinsella Ah I see now that my reasoning here was wrong.

Comment: So the finite cover obtained from compactness is important.

Comment: Yeah, that probably works. I think once you have $\mathscr{U}'$ I would use a "downward induction" (or whatever it's called) argument to get the cardinality of $\mathscr{U}'$ down to 1:  If M *is* connected then there exist two elements of $\mathscr{U}'$ that overlap. Replace both of them with their union (which is not M since the union is in $\mathscr{U}'$) to get a cover of smaller size.  Continue until you get a contradiction.  This is probably equivalent to what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your first attempt is that an element of $\mathscr{U}$ need not be contained in any element of $\mathscr{V}$.  For a simple counterexample, consider $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathscr{U}=\{(-n,n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  Then $\mathscr{U}$ is strongly additive but $\mathscr{V}$ will be empty!

Your fix works, because once you know that $\mathscr{U}'$ is finite then any of its elements will be contained in a maximal element by an easy induction.

Another way to fix the argument is to instead of looking at just the maximal elements of $\mathscr{U}$, look at equivalence classes that represent what the maximal elements "ought to be".  We may assume that $\emptyset\not\in\mathscr{U}$.  Define a relation $\sim$ on $\mathscr{U}$ by $U\sim V$ if $U\cup V$ is contained in an element of $\mathscr{U}$.  Using strong additivity, it is easy to see this is an equivalence relation, and any two inequivalent $U,V\in\mathscr{U}$ must be disjoint.  So, the unions of the equivalence classes are disjoint open sets that cover $M$, so by connectedness there can only be one equivalence class.  Finally, compactness would imply $\mathscr{U}$ has a finite subcover, but that would yield $M\in\mathscr{U}$ since any finitely many equivalent elements of $\mathscr{U}$ are all contained in an element of $\mathscr{U}$.